# Must the graph of a linear model always be a straight line of the form $y=mx+b$?

Tags: data-visualization, linear-model, linear

Must the graph of a linear model always be a straight line of the form $y=mx+b$?

I think that yes, but am checking, whether there might be some exceptions.

Comment: in the definition of "linear" models: yes. But could you explain more the context of your question? Did you want to use a regression model on a specific data base and want to know if the regression model must be linear?

Comment: No, a linear model remains linear even if you fit a polynomial. Check [this answer](http://stats.stackexchange.com/a/92087/67822). Also, if you're doing multiple regression, you will be generating a hyperplane.

Comment: @Metariat Well I'm plotting a linear regression model that has multiple parameters and I'm plotting it by changing the parameters. Since the model is fairly complex I was confused about the simplicity of the plot, which is a straight line.

Comment: The term linear refers to linear *in the parameters* only. Polynomials and splines are easy ways of introducing nonlinearity in the relationship between x and y while maintaining linearity in the parameters.

Comment: This question really seems to be asking "what exactly does 'linear' in 'linear model' refer to?"  If that is so, please visit [How to tell the difference between linear and non-linear regression models?](http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/148638)  A closely related thread is at http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/33876.

Comment: It may be hard to provide more specific answers w/o more information. Can you say more about your situation, your data & your model? Can you paste in some sample data, or your code, or a figure you want help interpreting?

Comment: @gung No I'm just asking whether linear **models** always exhibit a straight line plot. Since "linear" tends to mean such line.

Comment: @mavavilj, if that is your only question, it has been answered many times on the site, including in the links already provided.

Comment: There is a wonderful vagueness to this question: in the expression "$y=mx+b$", which is supposed to be the variable(s)?  Probably $x$ was intended, but this describes part of a "linear model" in the sense that it is expresses $y$ as a linear function of both $m$ and $b$--the linearity with respect to $x$ is irrelevant!